# Connecting 2 classes in javafx

Tags: java

I am making a project in javafx. My project has several classes and all classes are included in a package. What i need is to make a function of some other class working when a button from  another class is pressed. Below I include the code of my main class. All other classes in package has the same format as of the below code (that is, every class extends Application and start() method is used). My problem is that, when a button is pressed I don't know how to call the function of other class.

Comment: where is your main class? share it

Comment: @xxlali Can you tell me how to add code ?

Comment: @xxlali But the code is too large to comment. Is there a solution ?

Comment: don't to commet but to your question. you can edit your post, while editing copy yout code to your post

Comment: @xxlali When I tried to edit, some errors are coming. I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: @xxlali  Can you tell me how to add code without errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you should only have one class that extends from Application and only the start method of this class should be called. For multiple windows try using different 
[Stages](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html)

Comment: Should look something like this:
http://java-buddy.blogspot.co.at/2012/12/open-new-window-in-javafx-2.html